# Problems By Exception in Project

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am working on program , at one point of coding I have code which will generate exception **Every time** and i need to do that.

In other sense I want to use **catch** block more than **try** block.

I want to know this kind of coding can create problem in Apllication (in future after deployment) as there is always Exception Occurs?

**Is it harmful?**

```
try{
//throws exception every time
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//coding//Important part of code
}
```

Well I have other solution but what I want to know is **PROBLEMS** caused by this kind of Code.

I agree This is wrong but my Question is What are problems which can be created by this??

Comment: I don't understand why you are coding something that generates an exception every time. Exceptions should be exceptional.

Comment: I really cannot see the point of doing that...could you show us a piece of code, how you want to use it? Maybe then, somone will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is infinitely wrong!!! For you have not posted any details, I'll assume you are throwing different exceptions and then do something according to type of the thrown exception.

A better approach is to **return** a value (maybe an `enum`) and do processing according to it's value rather than the type of the thrown exception. There are of course better approaches to the problem, but I cannot say anything speciffic unless you give more details about what you are trying to do.

Eceptions should be used only in *exceptional* cases because:

1. Everybody expects that
2. No one would expect your use-case
3. Exceptions are slow compared to a `switch` on enum for instance
4. It's unintuitive and plain wrong
5. The people who will maintain your code will hate you :)

Comment: worse performance, unreadable and unmaintainable code, even if it works for now, it will be very hard and costly to modify/maintain your code in the future, it may lead to unexpected bugs in the future etc. Furthermore if you have some form of code-review in your company it would never pass it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can it create a problem? The simple answer is that it already is one. If your code throws an `Exception` every time, without fail, then why not get rid of the `try`-`catch` altogether? I highly doubt that what your code is doing in the try block cannot be structured any other way. As @user16547 mentioned, Exceptions should be *exceptional*. They were not designed to be used as an integral part of your application logic, or a perverted `goto`. Specific reasons *not* to do this:

- Throwing an `Exception` is costly, and you will seriously hurt your application if this is performance critical code.
- This hurts readability a good deal, as most people will not expect your code to be structured this way.
- It is generally a bad idea to catch the general `Exception` class, as this only further obfuscates your code, and masks other potential errors. Consider that some part of your code fails in the `try` block that you did not expect to. It still reverts to the catch, and could potentially cause your entire application to crash!

Without seeing your actual code, it is difficult to determine whether what you're doing is justified. However, as a general rule, this is not good practice, and is detrimental to performance, readability, and reliability.